# How implement Iterable in Map wrapper

Tags: java, java-8

I have field `Map<MyObject, String> myField`. And I use it as follows:

```
myField.forEach((myObject, text) -> myMethod(myObject, text));
```

I want wrap this field to new object:

```
class MyFieldWrapper {
    Map<MyObject, String> myField;
...
 //methods do somethings with myField
...
}
```

How implement Iterable in MyFieldWrapper for: `myFieldWrapper.forEach((myObject, text) -> myMethod(myObject, text));`?

Comment: A Map is not Iterable, If you want to be able to use forEach() on your wrapper, then add a forEach method that calls the map's forEach method. It should have the same signature, i.e. take a BiConsumer<? super MyObject, ? super String> as argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JBNizet as said, a Map is not Iterable, but if you want to have the forEach method, here there is a simple implementation:

```
class MyFieldWrapper {

    Map<MyObject, String> myField;
    ....

    public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super MyObject, ? super String> action){
        myField.forEach(action);
    }
}
```

EDITED: I make a mistake with `BiConsumer` template parameters.